# Home Up Button in ActionBar doesn't work

Tags: java, android, xml

I've a problem with the Home Up Button in `ActionBar`. I'm in a `PreferenceActivity` and in the `onCreate` i've put the following code:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

When I run my application it shows the Up Button but when I click on it nothing happens. So I put this code in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.mypackage.SystemInfo">
      <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.simonedev.androtools.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

But I still have the same problem. How can I solve it? 
Where is the problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add this method in your class, but outside the `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
setTitle("");
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 switch(item.getItemId())
 {

case android.R.id.home:
PreferenceActivity.this.onBackPressed(); 
break;


 }
 return true;   
 }
```

Now, after your comments. you may have to create a file called `action_bar.xml` in your res/menu folder, and add the following to it

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 </menu>
```

Comment: Now i've this error R cannot be resolved or is not a field I tried to clean my project but the problem remain. What can i do?

Comment: R cannot be resolved means that R.java file is not being created. Have you checked your .xml layout files? now errors in those? Also, did you create a .xml file in the res/menu folder for your actionbar?

Comment: In XML i haven't error. Whick file must be create? For an other PreferenceActivity it works perfectly without xml for action bar

Comment: Try a clean/rebuild. If that doesnt work then I editted my answer, check it out

Comment: I've the same problem also following your answer and tring cleaning project or rebooting eclipse

Comment: -1 Please do not use this.onBackPressed(); or finish()

Comment: @Benoit may I ask why should I not use onBackPressed() ?

Comment: the up and back have different purposes http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Answer (score 5):

### The wrong way up

You shouldn't use

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        //Do not use the following
        //PreferenceActivity.this.onBackPressed(); 
        //or
        //finish();
        break;
    }
    return true;   
}
```

### The proper way up

But instead follow [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/jgilfelt/this-way-up-implementing-effective-navigation-on-android) and [google guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)

The Manifest should add 1 more attribute

```
<activity android:name="com.example.mypackage.SystemInfo"
    android:parentActivityName="com.simonedev.androtools.MainActivity" >
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
    android:value="com.simonedev.androtools.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Copied code from [the presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/jgilfelt/this-way-up-implementing-effective-navigation-on-android): this would be the simple case

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        break;
    }
    return true;   
}
```

I invite you to read the whole [presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/jgilfelt/this-way-up-implementing-effective-navigation-on-android) for other more complex cases

Comment: How would this work if you had more than one parent? Say for example, activity A leads you to B, but C also leads you to B. So from activity B, how would we navigate to the page which just opened B it may be A or C

Comment: Good question, I don't have the answer to that, maybe it is also managed or maybe your interaction should be simpler.

Comment: But why would you want to copy the back button. you do not need an up button if it will exactly do the same as the physical back button

Comment: I thought the same, why do you need a copy of back button, but thats what OP wanted. Also, sometimes the interactions cant be simpler because you can reach the same page from 2 or more different pages.

Comment: In most cases I'd say you should make it simpler. ... what's OP ?... I still suggest you to read both links it can only give you more info ;)

Comment: Yeah I did go through them, they were pretty informative, thanks for sharing your insight

Comment: I think that instead of `break;` there should be `return true;` and the last statement should be changed from `return true;` to `return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)`. The returned value indicates if the event is consumed (true) or should if it should be processed further down the line.

Comment: case android.R.id.home:
        //PreferenceActivity.this.onBackPressed(); was exactly what I was looking for tho! Thanks!